# create reactjs class from json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

My goal: create js es6 class from json below.

**json:**

```
   {
    "Firms": {
        "Blacklist": [
            {
                "Description": "",
                "Firms": [
                    {
                        "FirmId": 64843222,
                        "FirmName": "insanis2",
                        "Comment": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Neutral": [],
        "Partners": []
    }
}
```

My attempted js code, you can see.

I have problems with array.

How add reactjs class array fields?

```
export default class FirmLists {
    Firms
}

export default class Firms {
    Blacklist //array 
    Neutral //array     
}

export default class Firm {
    FirmId: string = null;
    FirmName: string = null;
    Comment: string = null;
}

export default class Blacklist {
    Description: string = null;
    Firms //array
}

export default class Neutral {
    Description: string = null;
    Firms //array
}
```

This simple model from json

**update**: yes, we use flow

Comment: This doesn't look like JavaScript. Are you using Typescript? Or flow? Or experimental proposals?

Comment: you have to initialize the Arrays in the constructor.

Comment: i use reactjs @FelixKling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really working on ES2015, you can assign values in constructor.

```
class Firm {
  constructor() {
    this.Blacklist = [];
    this.Neutral = [];
    this.Partners = [];

    this.Blacklist.push(new BlacklistItem(...))
  }
}
```

But I recommend you to confirm what kind of language are you writing. There is no type declaration like `: string` in JavaScript, even in ECMAScript 2015+.

Such type declaration syntax exists in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). You can also extend JS syntax using [FlowJS](https://flowtype.org).
ReactJS is framework and it is not related to syntax.